# How to get request headers from the CefSharp browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

How can I retrieve the request headers when sending a POST request using the CefSharp browser?

Do I need to subscribe to an event?

Comment: Do you mean the *response* headers? No, you cannot.  See [issue 1025](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1025).

Comment: No I mean the request headers. Just like what Firebug Shows when sending a request using Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing `IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse`, you should have access to the request before it's sent to the server.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/43/CefSharp/IRequestHandler.cs#L23